# Visualize word frequency per category of variable - PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, cpu-word

I have a dataset containing two rows. Product group and Comment.
Product group has 42 unique numerical values. The comment column contains words which describe a complaint filed on the product.

I want to see which words occur most most per product group category. Using value_counts I can see the frequency of all the words. But I would like to see the word frequencies per product group category.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if you need more information just ask. Thank you!!

Comment: Group first then apply value counts. `df.groupby('Product group').Comment.value_counts()`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. The only problem is there are too many categories to be shown. How could I get this information for all categories?

Comment: @MatteoSabbatini, Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: Will do, thank you.